# How to create form inside session, and relate the data of that form to the registered user?

Tags: php, html, database, join, mysqli

I have a form right after the user signs up itself and the data goes to another table in the same database. I would like to associate the two tables so that when I log in I can show the info of the second table, and be able to do add even more data to that table with that user.

**Server**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $errors = array(); 
    $_SESSION['success'] = "";


    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','carsolve') or die("Nao conseguiu conectar à base de dados");

    // REGISTER USER
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['phone']);


        $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE  email = '$email' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($user){

        if($user['email'] === $email){
            array_push($errors, "Este email já existe.");
            }

        }

        // register user if there are no errors in the form
        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, phone) VALUES ('$username' , '$email' , '$password', '$phone')";

            mysqli_query($db,$query);
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are Logged";

            header('location: explicaçao1.php');
        }

    }

    // ... 

    // LOGIN USER
    if(isset($_POST['login_user'])){
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , $_POST['password']);    

        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $password = md5 ($password);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$email' AND password='$password' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
                $_SESSION['success'] = "Login com sucesso";
                header('location: page1.php');
            }else{
                array_push($errors, "Email e/ou Password incorretos.");
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $Marca = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Marca']);
        $Modelo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Modelo']);
        $Cilindrada = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Cilindrada']);
        $Potência = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Potência']);
        $Combustivel =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Combustivel']);
        $Matricula =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Matricula']);
        $Categoria =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Categoria']);
        $Tipo =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Tipo']);
        $Motor=  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Motor']);
        $Ano =  mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Ano']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO carros (Marca, Modelo, Cilindrada, Potência, Combustivel,
        Matricula, Categoria, Tipo, Motor, Ano) VALUES ('$Marca' , '$Modelo' , '$Cilindrada' , '$Potência' , '$Combustivel', '$Matricula' , 
        '$Categoria' , '$Tipo', '$Motor', '$Ano')";

        mysqli_query($db,$query);

        header('location: page1.php');
        }

    ?>
```

**Form after the user signs up**

```
<?php 
include('server/server.php') 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CarSolve</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/background.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carro.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/fqq3ceb.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="screen">
            <div class="conteudo">
              <div class="login">


                <form  method="post" action="carro.php">
                <div id="page" style="display:block">
                <h4>Vamos registar<br> o seu carro.</h4>
              <p>Informação disponível no Certificado de Matrícula.</p>
                <div id="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text"  name="Marca" id="Marca"placeholder="Marca (D.1)" required>
                </div>
                <div id="input-login">
                    <input class="input"  type="text"  name="Modelo" placeholder="Modelo (D.2)" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Cilindrada" placeholder="Cilindrada (P.1)" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Potência" placeholder="Potência útil máxima (P.2)" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Combustivel" placeholder="Combustível  (P.3)" required>
                </div>


              <div class="seguinte" >
              <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('page','page2')" class="button">Seguinte</a>
              </div>
              </div>

              <div id="page2" style="display:none">
              <h4>Está quase<br> a terminar!</h4>
              <p>Informação disponível no Certificado de Matrícula.</p>
              <div id="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text"  name="Matricula" placeholder="Número de matrícula (A)" required>
                </div>
                <div id="input-login">
                    <input class="input"  type="text"  name="Categoria" placeholder="Categoria nacional (J.1)" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Tipo" placeholder="Tipo de veículo (J.2)" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Motor" placeholder="Regime Nominal (P.4) " required >
                </div>
                <div class="input-login">
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="Ano" placeholder="Ano do Carro" required >
                </div>


              <div class="seguinte1">
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button2">Seguinte</button> 
              </div>
              <div class="anterior">
              <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('page2','page')" class="button1">Anterior</a>
              </div>
</div>
              </form>
              <img src="Imagens/onda2.svg" alt="logo" class="fundo1">
              <img src="Imagens/onda1.svg" alt="logo" class="fundo">


            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
   }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `foreign key` in tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways of achieving this. I'll give you a few starting points but I suggest you explore these further, find out what works best from a usability perspective and then build upon it.

Please also take note of my point at the end about binding SQL queries. Very important.

**Option 1: Using `$_SESSION[]` variables**

I noticed you are using `$_SESSION['success'] = "";` in your code, so you are familiar with `$_SESSION[]` variables. You could assign values to `$_SESSION['email']` and then check for that variable once the user submits the 2nd form and use it to associate the data with that email:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
```

**Option 2: Using `<input type = "hidden">`**

In this option you create hidden `<input>` fields in your 2nd form based on the user details from the 1st. For example:

```
<?php
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['$email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['$email']);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?=$email;>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?=$phone;>">
```

**Option 3: Using a token**

This is a little more complicated but I'll explain why I'm suggesting it. You could generate a random token in your first form and submit it then, in a new column in your database, add it along with the rest of your sql query.

Use this token as a hidden  as in Option 2, to connect the data from form 1 to form 2.

So in form 1 you  would look like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="form2?token=<?=rndtoken;?>">
```

This option is helpful if you want to send an email to the user after form 1 with a link to continue completing the form. You would send a link like continueregistering.php?token=thisismyrandomtokencompletelyuniquetothisuser and then check for the token using:

```
$_GET['token']
```

...so there are a few different ways, and many more. Worth exploring each and understanding what each one does, how it works and how you can apply to your site.

Make sure you check out the isset() function of PHP so you can check if variable exist, in case someone jumps to form 2 without going through form 1:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

**Final Point (very important)**

Please learn about prepared SQL statements. Right now you are using things like email = '$email" and password = "password" in your SQL statement. This makes your site very susceptible to  malicious code being inserted into your DB and your site. I get the impressions you are in your early days of PHP programming but this really is a must-learn so please take a look:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

And finally, you need to hash your passwords before putting them in a database. Right now you are inserting them as plain text. So, if I got a hold of your user database, I could see your password as mypassword123.

Hashing passwords, applied a mathematical algorithm to passwords to encrypt them so hackers can't see the actual passwords. You can find out more here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the advice!